# For what $a, b, C$ is $C(5u_{n+1}+au_{n-1} - bu_{n})\approx u^{\prime\prime}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, finite-differences

We are trying to approximate the value of at $x=nh$ and we know that $u_{n+1}=u(x+h)$, $u_{n}=u(x)$ and $u_{n-1}=u(x-h)$. The question is, for what values of $a, b$ and $C$ is the following an approximation?

$C(5u_{n+1}+au_{n-1} - bu_{n})\approx u^{\prime\prime}$

I am not too sure what this question is asking. I am familiar with the traditional central difference approximation for the second derivative, but does there have to be some kind of relationship between the constants above for the approximation to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a special case, consider $u_n=c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2$. Then one can show that
\begin{align}
5u_{n+1}+au_{n-1}-b u_n
&=(5+a-b)c_0+[5-a+(5+a-b)n]c_1\\&\;\;\;\;+[5 + a + 2n(5 - a) + (5+a-b) n^2]c_2.
\end{align}

But the second derivative of $u(x)=u_n$ should be independent of $c_0,c_1$, so we need the above coefficients of $c_0,c_1$ to vanish identically. From the former, we have $b=a+5$; from the latter, we have $5-a+(5+a-b)n=5-a=0.$ Hence $a=5,b=10,$ in which case the proposed approximation for $u''(x)$ is $$C(5u_{n+1}-10u_n + 5u_{n-1})=10Cc_2.$$

But $u(x)=u_n=c_0+c_1(x/h)+c_2(x/h)^2$ since $x=nh$, so $u''(x)=2c_2/h^2$. So for the above to work, we need $10Cc_2 = 2c_2/h^2\implies C=1/5h^2.$ Hence the approximation must be of the form

$$\frac{1}{h^2}(u_{n+1}-2u_n+u_{n-1})\approx u''(x)$$ which if written in terms of $u(x)$ is just the familiar central difference formula for $u''(x)$.

Comment: Why should we suppose that $u_n$ takes the form in the first line?

Comment: @wrb98 It's a special case; if it doesn't work for that one, it can't work in general. (Edited accordingly.)

Comment: Oh I see. Could you please explain a little more how you derived the first equation to get the LHS of the approximation?

Comment: It looks to be a Taylor series, but how can you be sure which order of terms you should reject?

Comment: No, this is not a Taylor series (though one could certainly rewrite the answer to do so). I'm simply picking a special case where the second derivative is especially simple (it doesn't depend on $c_0,c_1$, for instance) and arguing that the proposed form will fail if $a,b,C$ aren't of the stated form. (The validity of the resulting approximation comes by identifying it with the central difference formula.)

Comment: Yes it was the $5u_{n+1} + au_{n-1} - bu_{n}=\ldots$ bit that I wasn't sure of. How did you get the RHS of that?

Comment: I plugged $u_n=c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2$ into $5u_{n+1}+$etc and expanded by hand. Nothing but algebra there.

Comment: Of course, silly question.

Answer (score 1):

hint:$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u(x+h)+u(x-h)-2u(x)}{h^2}=u''(x)\\\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u'(x+h)-u'(x-h)-2(0)}{2h}=\\
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u''(x+h)+u''(x-h)}{2}=u''(x)$$
now if you take $$a=5,b=-10\\5u(n+1)+5u(n-1)-10u\sim h^2 u''$$

Comment: Can you please explain the second and third lines? Where did the limits involving $\prime$ and $\prime\prime$ come from, and why is there a 0 term?

Comment: I used l'hopital's rule

Comment: Ah, so were you just proving the top line using that rule?

Comment: If you multiply the approximation given by the first line by 5 then surely the final line should be $\approx 5h^2 u^{\prime\prime}$?

Comment: sure.you can expand Taylor series form of $u(x+h),u(x-h)$ but I am not sure this was "What you look for "!

Comment: Your choice of $b=-20$ is not consistent with a coefficient of $-10$ under the OP's notation. (Should be $b=10$.)